# igraph: edges are not clipped to vertices in undicrected graphs

Tags: r, igraph

When I change the `vertex.size` in `igraph`, the edges are not clipped to the vertices, they end a few dots/pixel next to the vertices. Example:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(13)
g <- barabasi.game(500, directed = F)
plot(g, vertex.size = 2, edge.curved = T, vertex.label = NA, edge.arrow.mode = "-",
layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

It seems like it's not applying to a directed graphs as the arrow is plotted at the end of an edge.

Is there a way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `edge.arrow.size` and it seems to fix it.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(13)
g <- barabasi.game(500, directed = F)
plot(g, vertex.size = 2, edge.curved = T, vertex.label = NA, edge.arrow.mode = "-",   
edge.arrow.size=0.01,layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

i.e.

[image]